# Запуск airgram на Windows. Dynamic Linking Error: Win32 error 126

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, telegram

Я сбилдил tdlib на Windows. При попытке запустить airgram-бота консоль выдает ошибку `Dynamic Linking Error: Win32 error 126`. Пробовал гуглить. Скорей всего ошибка в том, что неправильно указан путь к tdjson в параметре `command`. Вот мой код:

```
const airgram = new Airgram({
  apiId: 9999999,
  apiHash: "myhash",
  command: "", //что тут писать?
  logVerbosityLevel: 2,
})
```

Я перепробовал разные директории, но результат всегда один. Подскажите, какой путь нужно указывать в `command`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Занимаюсь тем же поиском решения, по идее везде говорится про tdjson.dll . Соответственно в command нужно поместить путь до файла, пример - "путь-до-собранного-репозитория-td/build/Release/tdjson.dll", но мне такое не помогло.

Еще могу посоветовать накатить Ubuntu терминал и включить подсистему Linux в Windows. Соответственно все команды надо будет выполнять через этот терминал, путь к файлу уже будет "/usr/local/lib/libtdjson.so"

P.S.
Нашел решение сие проблеме. идем в папку с td > build > Release. Содержимое папки переносим в корень с js файлом, после код отрабатывает без ошибок. Попытки перенести файлы в папку и прописать путь к ней не увенчались успехом.

P.S 2
Если найдется способ перенести файлы из корня, напишите в комменты)